# Unable to call a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a view in with a name test.php, now I want to run this view but I have no idea about CodeIgniter and how I can run this view. I am very new to CodeIgniter.

The below is my test.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>First codeigniter prog</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Testing page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html) is very useful, the [views](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) and [controllers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) pages are particularly relevant.

---

Assuming your view file is saved in `application/views/`, you should load your view in a controller like so:

```
$this->load->view('test');
```

The default controller in CodeIgniter is *Welcome* (in `application/controllers/`).

You could add this line to the `index()` function:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

Then view your view in the browser:

```
yoururl.com/index.php/welcome/
```

Comment: i have write the above code in welcome but my page is still not running @lefters

Comment: What is actually happening? Are you getting an error? A blank page? Something else?